# Different templates for different category tags

Tags: categories, theme-development, templates, tags

Is there any method to create different template in a theme for different category tags search?
For example, I have category 'blog' and category 'glossary' - there is no any similar tag for both categories.
I need to open tags from blogs this way:
/blog/tag/any-tag-blog
/glossary/tag/any-tag-glossary

what method can I use in the theme for splitting tags result and to have different template pages for these categories?

Answer (score 0):

You can make the following templates named:

```
category-blog.php
category-glossary.php
```

If these are custom taxonomies:

```
taxonomy-blog.php
taxonomy-glossary.php
```

Source:

https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/Screenshot-2019-01-23-00.20.04.png

Comment: I know this way but this is not what I need. 'Blog' and 'Glossary'  are posts categories - they have different templates. The posts have their tags - posts from blog category have any tags and posts from glossary category have other tags. I need the templates for 'blog/tag/some-tag' and other template for 'glossary/tag/other-tag' . I found a way with $_GET. But this is not same.

Answer (score 0):

Dedicated tag or category pages are very doable.

You would use the following format `category-catslug.php` for each tag you want a special template for.

There is [a help page covering this in greater detail](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Here is the hierarchy of files for templates in WordPress.

[image]

To then show tags on the category page, you would have to write some custom code in the custom category file to use the loop with [wp_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) to generate your results. Probably by inspecting `$wp->request` and/or `$wp->query_vars`.

Comment: I asked for another thing. This template is for a tag (tag-{slug}.php – If the tag’s slug is sometag, WordPress will look for tag-sometag.php.) I am looking for template which will combine category + tag template. I found a decision in URL like this: //site.com/category/?tag=sometag . But I try to find a decision to open like this: site.com/category/tag/sometag - the template should be same for all tags in this category, for another categories tags I need another template.

Comment: @ALexanderLead I see. I've updated my answer to reflect this part of the question.